# JQuery toggleclass on click and disable when clicking on the other div or outside the div

Tags: jquery, toggle, toggleclass, siblings

I've been trying to find a JQuery script that does the following: Toggle enable/disable class once I click on the **apply-class-here** here div. It should also disable the class once you click outside of the div or click on one of the other apply class div's.

I already found a script that does exactly that, but I cannot seem to get it to work once the div is contained within a couple of other elements. (tile-wrapper > tile > **apply-class-here**)

```
<div class="tile-wrapper">
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="apply-class-here">Block</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tile-wrapper">
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="apply-class-here">Block</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tile-wrapper">
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="apply-class-here">Block</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tile-wrapper">
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="apply-class-here">Block</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script I found, it only seems to work on elements which are not contained within any other elements like div's etc.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $(function () {
            $('.apply-class-here').click(function(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('overlay-active');
            $(this).toggleClass('overlay-active');
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            $('.apply-class-here').removeClass('overlay-active');
        });
    });
});
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem. I just cannot seem to get it to work the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `$(this).siblings().removeClass('overlay-active');` because `apply-class-here` are not siblings

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.apply-class-here').click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $('.overlay-active').not(this).removeClass('overlay-active');
        $(this).toggleClass('overlay-active');
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
        $('.apply-class-here').removeClass('overlay-active');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5xz641r4/)

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to select sibling elements when there arent any with:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('overlay-active');
```

Change your code to (and remove the nested document ready calls):

```
$('.apply-class-here').click(function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); 
    $(this).closest('.tile-wrapper').siblings().not($(this)).each(function(){
        $(this).find('.apply-class-here').removeClass('overlay-active');
    })
    $(this).toggleClass('overlay-active');
});
$(document).click(function () {
    $('.apply-class-here').removeClass('overlay-active');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wyhyauv1/)**